# Real Time Bar chart using Highcharts and AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

Using a **Highcharts** example ([here](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic)), I have loaded a bar chart in **AngularJs**.

HTML code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-lang="en" ng-app="myModule">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/6.0.7/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<script>
angular.module('myModule',[])
.controller('myController',function($q, $scope, $http){

    $scope.cnt = 1;
    var t = 0;
    setInterval(function(cnt){

        fetchData($scope.cnt).then(function(success){

            $scope.chartOptions={
                    chart: {
                        type: 'bar',
                        events:{
                            load:function(){
                                var rowClass = this.series[0];
                                console.log("rowClass : "+rowClass);
                            }
                        } 
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'ClassNames By Count Chart'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'Admin Chart'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: $scope.rows,
                        title: {
                            text: null
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Population (millions)',
                            align: 'high'
                        },
                        labels: {
                            overflow: 'justify'
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: ' millions'
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        bar: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        x: -40,
                        y: 80,
                        floating: true,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
                        shadow: true
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Year 1800',
                        data: (function(){
                            var data = [];
                            var i;
                            console.log("In Series function() : $scope.num : "+$scope.num );    //Update is being done propertly
                            for(i=1;i<4;i=i+1){
                                data.push($scope.num[i]);
                            }
                            return data;
                        }())
                    }, {    
                        name: 'Year 1900',
                        data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
                    }, {
                        name: 'Year 2000',
                        data: [814, 841, 3714, 727, 31]
                    }, {
                        name: 'Year 2016',
                        data: [1216, 1001, 4436, 738, 40]
                    }]
            };

            if(t==0){
                t = t+1;
                Highcharts.chart('container',$scope.chartOptions);
            }
        },function(error){
            console.log("in error functio : "+error);
        });
    },2000);

    var cnt = 0;
    var str = "str";
    setInterval(function(){
        str = str+cnt;
        cnt++;
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url : "http://localhost:8080/hello/"+str+"/3"
        }).then(function success(data){
        }, function error(data){
            console.log("error "+data.data);
        });
    },5000);

    var fetchData = function(cnt){
        $scope.cnt = $scope.cnt+1;

        var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http({
                method : "GET",
                url : "http://localhost:8080/hello"
            }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
                $scope.myRes = response.data;
                $scope.rows = $scope.myRes;
                var i;
                $scope.num = [];
                for(i=0;i<4;i=i+1){
                    $scope.num.push(++cnt*110);
                }

                deferred.resolve();
            }, function myError(response) {
                console.log("error");
                $scope.myRes = response;
                deferred.reject();
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    };  

});

</script>
<body ng-controller="myController">
    <hcbar options="chartOptions"></hcbar>
    <div id="container"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now I require to load the bar counts in the chart to be loaded dynamically that is as the count is updated in Database the new values have to be reflected in the chart **(Real Time Data)**

You will see I ahve written the **data : function** in my file which updates the data array in a loop:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Year 1800',
    data: (function(){
        var data = [];
        var i;
        console.log("In Series function() : $scope.num : "+$scope.num );    //Update is being done propertly
        for(i=1;i<4;i=i+1){
            da.push($scope.num[i]);
        }
        returndata;
    }())
},
```

The updated values are correctly printed in console but are **NOT BEING REFLECTED IN THE CHART BAR!**

I know there is this function **addPoint()** which adds a point to the array. But here I do not want a new Object in the **series** array but the updated values in the **series[0].data** array!

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Shouldn't `returndata` be `return data`? Also, I think `da.push` needs to be `data.push`

Answer (score 1):

If you put your values in **$scope** and use like following.

```
series: [{
          data: [
                { name: 'Year 1800', y: $scope.num1, color: 'red' },
                { name: 'Year 1900', y: $scope.num2, color: 'green' },
                { name: 'Year 2000', y: $scope.num3, color: 'blue' },
                { name: 'Year 2016', y: $scope.num4, color: 'yellow' }
            ]
        }],
```

when you will update **$scope.num1**, it will definitely **update** in chart.

here is a **WORKING** Example.

```
$scope.chartOptions = {
        chart: {
          type: 'column',
          spacingLeft: 0,
          spacingRight: 0,
          height: 300
        },
        title: {
          text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: ['1800', '1900', '2000', 2016'],
          crosshair: true
        },
        yAxis: {
          min: 0,
          tickInterval: 20,
          title: {
            text: ''
          },
          labels:
          {
            enabled: false
          }
        },
        legend: {
          enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
          column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
          }
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
          data: [
                { name: 'Year 1800', y: $scope.num1, color: 'red' },
                { name: 'Year 1900', y: $scope.num2, color: 'green' },
                { name: 'Year 2000', y: $scope.num3, color: 'blue' },
                { name: 'Year 2016', y: $scope.num4, color: 'yellow' }
            ]
        }]
     };
```

Comment: Hi Ghazni, however this will populate the array data but it is not rendering the Highchart then. WIll highchart API be able to read data in this format? I have kept the data as  data:[{
             name:"Year 1800",
             y:$scope.num 
            }]

Comment: yes; it should read. what error is showing on rendering to you ?

Comment: Even on console when I access the values as 'var rowClass = this.series[0].data[0].y;'  . It shows undefined!

Comment: Thnx Ghanzi, working now. I added that in a For loop function.

Comment: Hi Ghazni, though that values are now showing but the values in the bar still not change as the values in $scope.num array changes!. I do am getting $scope.num array properly formatted each time but the values in graph load for the initial values not to the constantly changing values!

Comment: did you tried? $scope.$apply(); after changing the scope values?